# How to read the contents of a PDF file?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on my thesis, and the application is going to use **natural language question answering**. I've read about several ideas and followed discussions about natural language question answering, but I can't seem to find good answers.

**Question: How do I get answers from PDF, plain text, or MS Word file?**

If I want to search for a topic in a PDF file I would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the topic/idea, but it wouldn't return all the details; just like a table of contents, it would give the starting page and end page of a chapter. That's what I want for the logic. It would determine where the chapter ends without using pages or numbers. Is there any algorithm capable of doing that?

Comment: To keep things simple, I think you should avoid PDF files because the format can be extremely complicated. There are some tools to extract information from them but as far as I remember they are all very expensive. Stick with good old .txt files if you can.

Comment: Of course, you can just do a "search" in Acrobat Reader ;)  There are many open source and commercial libraries that read .PDF, including the Adobe PDF SDK, GnuPdf, and PdfBox.

Comment: Laurent is correct - if you don't *have* to use .pdf, then *definitely* use clear text, instead ;)

Comment: yes i would like to use .txt file instead but the file that i would use is a 150pages PDF file. So if i want a .txt file i would have to copy PDF to .txt?

Comment: Is this question about (a) how to convert PDF to plain text, (b) how to convert all kinds of formats, including PDF and MS Word, to plain text, (c) how to make a topic search / semantic fuzzy search algorithm, or (d) how to build such an algorithm into a PDF viewer? (a) is suggested by the title, (b) by the bold part in the middle, and (c) and (d) by the final part.

Comment: @jogojapan you have answered my question by the final part. I was looking for a algorithm that would search topics and its content. I would like to learn and make a semantic fuzzy search algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/) to read PDF file Contents.